# Gui additional output clarity

Tags: java, user-interface, calculator

I have recoded my GUI correctly, where user inputs Initial Balance, Annual Rate, and Number of years.  It calculates and outputs numbers up 15 years. I.E (10000, 2.5, 5) produces 5 numbers correctly.  Now question is, the user decides to retry again with different input numbers, the original 5 numbers that was outputted before, remains in the calculator, with the new numbers being outputted with the 2nd retry.   I'm not sure if that is how its suppose to be? Or Am I suppose to clear out the 5 original numbers?

Here is the code:  Otherwise, i'm fine with the coding, just need some clarification.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SavingAccountFrame extends JFrame{
private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 400;
private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
private static final int AREA_ROWS = 10;
private static final int AREA_COLUMNS = 30;
private static final double DEFAULT_RATE = 5;
private static final double INITIAL_BALANCE = 1000;

private JLabel amountLabel1;
private JLabel amountLabel2;
private JLabel amountLabel3;
private JTextField amountField1;
private JTextField amountField2;
private JTextField amountField3;
private JButton button;
private JTextArea resultArea;
private JPanel panel;
//private BankAccount account;

public SavingAccountFrame(){
    //account = new BankAccount(INITIAL_BALANCE);
    resultArea = new JTextArea(AREA_ROWS, AREA_COLUMNS);
    resultArea.setEditable(false);
    createTextField();
    createButton();
    createPanel();
    setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
}

private void createTextField(){
    final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
    amountLabel1 = new JLabel("Initial Balance: ");
    amountField1 = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
    amountField1.setText("" + 100000);
    amountLabel2 = new JLabel("Annual Rate: ");
    amountField2 = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
    amountField2.setText("" + 3.5);
    amountLabel3 = new JLabel("Number of Years: ");
    amountField3 = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
    amountField3.setText("" + 15);
}

private void createButton(){
    button = new JButton("Calculate");
    class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            double interest;
            double balance = Double.parseDouble(amountField1.getText());
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(amountField2.getText());
            double years = Double.parseDouble(amountField3.getText());
            for(int i = 0; i < years; i++){
                interest = balance * rate / 100;
                balance = balance + interest;
                resultArea.append("$" + df.format(balance) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}

private void createPanel(){
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.add(amountLabel1);
    panel.add(amountLabel2);
    panel.add(amountLabel3);
    panel.add(amountField1);
    panel.add(amountField2);
    panel.add(amountField3);
    panel.add(button);
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(resultArea);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    add(panel);
}
}
```

Comment: `"I'm not sure if that is how its suppose to be? Or Am I suppose to clear out the 5 original numbers?"` -- it is supposed to be how you want it to be -- or if it's an assignment, then it's how your instructor wants it. If the latter, then perhaps it's time to ask for clarification.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  What I read from assignment, was just stating to calculate the algorithms correctly, and utilizing the jscroll when inputting years that will cause the text to be scrolled down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending the results to the `resultArea` each time you click the `Calculate` button

You have (at least) two choices...

Build up a `String` value of the output and use `resultArea.setText` method to set the text, which will clear the field and replace it with the text you supply...

```
private void createButton(){
    button = new JButton("Calculate");
    class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            double interest;
            double balance = Double.parseDouble(amountField1.getText());
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(amountField2.getText());
            double years = Double.parseDouble(amountField3.getText());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(128);
            for(int i = 0; i < years; i++){
                interest = balance * rate / 100;
                balance = balance + interest;
                sb.append("$" + df.format(balance) + "\n");
            }
            resultArea.setText(sb.toString());
        }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

Or use `setText` and pass it a `null` or empty `String` to clear it before you up date the field

```
private void createButton(){
    button = new JButton("Calculate");
    class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
            double interest;
            double balance = Double.parseDouble(amountField1.getText());
            double rate = Double.parseDouble(amountField2.getText());
            double years = Double.parseDouble(amountField3.getText());
            resultArea.setText(null);
            for(int i = 0; i < years; i++){
                interest = balance * rate / 100;
                balance = balance + interest;
                resultArea.append("$" + df.format(balance) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    ActionListener listener = new AddInterestListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Very helpful and clarified with I was doing with  the code and how to fix it up.  Appreciate it. :)  When the minutes are over, i'll click on the checkmark

Comment: Yeah, I think I like the results better with clearing out the output when user wants to retry many times.